# Compiling Oracle schema with debug info

Tags: oracle

We have a script that creates a number of new Oracle packages, triggers, views and functions on an Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 database.

After that, all these objects are compiled. We first used DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA to compile all of these objects. However, COMPILE_SCHEMA does not add debug info. We would also like to add debug info.

What's the best way to do this? This is our current algorithm:

1. Create all objects
2. Compile all objects in debug mode one by one. This leaves a number of objects invalid that have references to objects that came later in the list.
3. Recompile everything using DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA so that all objects are valid.

In this scenario, all objects are compiled twice, which is clearly not optimal. There are a lot of objects so it takes a very long time. We want to speed it up.

Is there anything available that does the same as DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA, but with debug info included?

Comment: Wouldn't `DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA (schema => user, compile_all => false, reuse_settings => true);` cut that down a lot? Or might that hit the maximum-iterations limit if you have a lot of dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/alter_function.htm):

> **DEBUG**
>
> Has the same effect as `PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=1`—instructs the PL/SQL compiler to generate and store the code for use by the PL/SQL debugger. Oracle recommends using `PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=1` instead of DEBUG.

So you can set that before you create your objects, or before you recompile the schema. To match what SQL Developer does when you 'compile for debug' though, you need to set `PLSQL_DEBUG` to true as well. Here's a quick demo:

```
create or replace package p42 as
  function f return number;
end p42;
/

create or replace package body p42 as
  function f return number is
  begin
    return 42;
  end f;
end p42;
/

select name, type, plsql_optimize_level, plsql_debug
from user_plsql_object_settings where name = 'P42';

NAME                           TYPE         PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL PLSQL_DEBUG
------------------------------ ------------ -------------------- -----------
P42                            PACKAGE                         2 FALSE       
P42                            PACKAGE BODY                    2 FALSE       


alter session set plsql_optimize_level = 1;
alter session set plsql_debug = true;

exec dbms_utility.compile_schema(user);

select name, type, plsql_optimize_level, plsql_debug
from user_plsql_object_settings where name = 'P42';

NAME                           TYPE         PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL PLSQL_DEBUG
------------------------------ ------------ -------------------- -----------
P42                            PACKAGE                         1 TRUE        
P42                            PACKAGE BODY                    1 TRUE
```

Of course you can just alter your session before creating the objects in the first place, but if you know you're going to always recompile the schema anyway - if you have to recompile everything, not just invalid objects - then waiting until then is probably OK. But if you do create the objects with debugging enabled, you can still recompile and retain that with:

```
DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => user, reuse_settings => true);
```

... if you want to recompile everything, or if you only want to recompile invalid objects:

```
DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => user, compile_all => false, reuse_settings => true);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :-)

I noticed the plsql_optimize_level in the docs but I didn't set the plsql_debug = true.

Comment: For me `reuse_settings` has to be set to `false`, which is the default. Otherwise the packages are not recompiled with debug info!

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the object one by one

```
SELECT PO.OWNER,PO.OBJECT_NAME,PO.OBJECT_TYPE,PO.DEBUGINFO
,'ALTER ' || REPLACE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE') || ' ' || owner || '.' || object_name ||DECODE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY',' COMPILE BODY;',' COMPILE;') COPILE_NO_DEBUG
,'ALTER ' || REPLACE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE') || ' ' || owner || '.' || object_name ||DECODE(object_type,'PACKAGE BODY',' COMPILE DEBUG BODY;',' COMPILE DEBUG;') COPILE_WITH_DEBUG
FROM   SYS.ALL_PROBE_OBJECTS PO
--WHERE OBJECT_NAME='YOUR_DEFINITION_PKG' AND DEBUGINFO IN ('F','T')
ORDER BY owner, object_type, object_name;
```